# Sort list in decreasing (according to length) order in R

Tags: r, list, igraph

I have a list in the following format. I want to sort my list in decreasing order according to the length of each list.

```
+ 6/9453
```

indicating the length of that list.For component 1 there are six list of different length, so i want to sort all the component list in decreasing order. The zero length element is not to be considered.

```
mylist:

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
+ 6/9453 vertices, named:
[1] VEGFA  EPHB2  GRIN2B AP2M1  KCNJ11 ABCC8 


[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]][[1]]
+ 4/9453 vertices, named:
[1] VEGFA VTN   PRKCA ADCY5


[[1]][[3]]
[[1]][[3]][[1]]
+ 0/9453 vertices, named:


[[1]][[4]]
[[1]][[4]][[1]]
+ 4/9453 vertices, named:
[1] VEGFA KDR   GRB2  ADRB1


[[1]][[5]]
[[1]][[5]][[1]]
+ 3/9453 vertices, named:
[1] VEGFA AKT1  AKT2 


[[1]][[6]]
[[1]][[6]][[1]]
+ 4/9453 vertices, named:
[1] VEGFA CTGF  AP3D1 AP3S2



[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]]
+ 6/9453 vertices, named:
[1] HHEX   EFEMP2 TP53   ARIH2  ENSA   ABCC8 


[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]][[1]]
+ 5/9453 vertices, named:
[1] HHEX  TLE1  POLB  PRKCA ADCY5


[[2]][[3]]
[[2]][[3]][[1]]
+ 0/9453 vertices, named:


[[2]][[4]]
[[2]][[4]][[1]]
+ 5/9453 vertices, named:
[1] HHEX  TLE1  ATN1  MAGI2 ADRB1


[[2]][[5]]
[[2]][[5]][[1]]
+ 4/9453 vertices, named:
[1] HHEX JUN  ESR1 AKT2


[[2]][[6]]
[[2]][[6]][[1]]
+ 6/9453 vertices, named:
[1] HHEX  TLE1  CDK1  BUB1  AP3B1 AP3S2



[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[[3]][[1]][[1]]
+ 7/9453 vertices, named:
[1] PPP1R3A RPS6KA1 MAPK1   TP53    ARIH2   ENSA    ABCC8  


[[3]][[2]]
[[3]][[2]][[1]]
+ 4/9453 vertices, named:
[1] PPP1R3A PLN     PRKACA  ADCY5  


[[3]][[3]]
[[3]][[3]][[1]]
+ 0/9453 vertices, named:


[[3]][[4]]
[[3]][[4]][[1]]
+ 4/9453 vertices, named:
[1] PPP1R3A RPS6KA1 GRB2    ADRB1  


[[3]][[5]]
[[3]][[5]][[1]]
+ 4/9453 vertices, named:
[1] PPP1R3A RPS6KA1 PDPK1   AKT2   


[[3]][[6]]
[[3]][[6]][[1]]
+ 6/9453 vertices, named:
[1] PPP1R3A RPS6KA1 MAPK1   IRS1    AP3S1   AP3S2
```

I used one command i don't know is it right way to do it.

```
mylist[sort(order(mylist)]
```

but it is not working and gave error:

```
Error: unexpected ']' in "mylist[sort(order(mylist)]"
```

Give any solution for this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe just use `order()`, not `sort(order())`. Your error is caused by not having a closing parenthesis for `sort`... as I guess you can tell.

Comment: Hello Frank, I just use the     order()

Comment: and close the parenthesis still it's not working.

Comment: Please help me to solve out this problem.Any help appreciate.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas and don't know the igraph package well. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable will come along and help, though it is often slow on weekends.